# Define multiple fields to copy in graphical modeler in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, qgis-modeler

I am looking to find the correct syntax for copying a defined set of fields when using the "Join attributes by field value tool" in the graphical modeler in QGIS 3.6.

I would like to know how the syntax for this when selecting multiple fields as I cannot seem to work it out. For example if I only wanted to join "Field_1" and "Field_2".

Please see my image below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried choosing said fields outside the modeller and copying the style of that notation into the modeller?

Comment: I thought about that too but it only shows the number of items selected because you choose from a drop down.

Comment: Protocol shows the python-code to be `'FIELDS_TO_COPY' : ['column1',column2']` - maybe if you write the columns out using this syntaX?

Comment: @Erik thank you for the suggestion - it doesn't appear to work unfortunately.

Comment: I guess you tried a syntax analogue to the field calculator, like `"column1","column2"` ?

Comment: @Erik I just tried that variation with and without square brackets and still no luck - this is a real head scratcher

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seperate them with a semicolon: field1;field2

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was that simple!